# Compound path - Fill doesn't match shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, fill

[image]This is a really simple file. Just a outlined text, made into a compound path. It's weird that the fill doesn't match the outline (in blue) does anyone know what's happening here?

Comment: Align to pixel grid?

Comment: I suspect the blue outline isn't the path. It's the bounding box of the shape. To see the path selected use the Direct Selection tool (A)

Comment: When I use the direct selection tool the same path is selected.